# Playing a sound file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

I am working on a program that will have a music component.  Basically when certain buttons are pressed I want to play specific song files.  I have been looking a lot into playing sound in Java but nothing has worked for me yet.  I am currently playing around with some code I found in a tutorial however I am not sure how to specify the file.

I keep getting a `FileNotFoundExecption` so I'm obviously referencing the file incorrectly.  I have the `.wav` file on my desktop and I also have it in a resource source folder in my project.  A part of the code is below, any ideas on how I reference the file?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // specify the sound to play
    // (assuming the sound can be played by the audio system)
    File soundFile = new File("/desktop/14_Wonderland.wav");
    AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

    // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(sound);

    // due to bug in Java Sound, explicitly exit the VM when
    // the sound has stopped.
    clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                event.getLine().close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

    // play the sound clip
    clip.start();
}
```

Comment: `/desktop/14_Wonderland.wav` that won't get you to the desktop.. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981594/get-absolute-desktop-path).  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder) is another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you are having trouble finding a file, I know this is not ideal for most cases, but you can try using a [JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774652/how-to-use-jfilechooser-to-find-a-file-location) (I linked an example).

From that, you can either just use the file found or you can output the location of the file chosen so that you can see how to model your file path. I hope this helps!

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind your default music app opening when you want to play a sound,
you could do this:
For Mac OS X: Desktop.open(FilePath);
For Windows :  Runtime.exec(FilePath);

Answer (score 0):

I know it does not answer your question about the File exception (others already did), but you can use this code to play sounds (you might need to play with it a little bit to fit your needs):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class PlaySound {
    private static boolean tryToInterruptSound = false;
    private static long mainTimeOut = 3000;
    private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static synchronized Thread playSound(final File file) {

        Thread soundThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Clip clip = null;
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = null;
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                    AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
                    long audioFileLength = file.length();
                    int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
                    float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
                    long durationInMiliSeconds = 
                            (long) (((float)audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate)) * 1000);

                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.start();
                    System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": sound started playing!");
                    Thread.sleep(durationInMiliSeconds);
                    while (true) {
                        if (!clip.isActive()) {
                            System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": sound got to it's end!");
                            break;
                        }
                        long fPos = (long)(clip.getMicrosecondPosition() / 1000);
                        long left = durationInMiliSeconds - fPos;
                        System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": time left: " + left);
                        if (left > 0) Thread.sleep(left);
                    }
                    clip.stop();  
                    System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": sound stoped");
                    clip.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": sound interrupted while playing.");
                }
            }
        };
        soundThread.setDaemon(true);
        soundThread.start();
        return soundThread;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread soundThread = playSound(new File("C:\\Booboo.wav"));
        System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": playSound returned, keep running the code");
        try {   
            Thread.sleep(mainTimeOut );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (tryToInterruptSound) {
            try {   
                soundThread.interrupt();
                Thread.sleep(1); 
                // Sleep in order to let the interruption handling end before
                // exiting the program (else the interruption could be handled
                // after the main thread ends!).
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": End of main thread; exiting program " + 
                (soundThread.isAlive() ? "killing the sound deamon thread" : ""));
    }
}
```

Try using an absolute file path or a path in your classpath to solve the FileNotFound exception.

Comment: Thank you! Both this code and the code I was using before seem to be on the right track now that I fixed the file path.  However, I am now getting a LineUnavailableException because my requested buffer was too large. I'm looking into this exception now